# По данному натуральному N вычислите сумму выражения

Tags: javascript

По данному натуральному N вычислите сумму `1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2`. Результат выведите в мини-браузер. Например, при `N = 128` ответ `707264`. Значение `N` менять нельзя. Решать можно только при помощи цикла `for`.

Comment: На каком языке? Что вы уже пробовали и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Заплатите одногрупнику, он вам решит.

Comment: Циклы: инструкция for в JavaScript

Comment: мне очень хочется научиться программирования но проблема в том что учиться ему мне дал возможность муж и не хочет помогать и я хочу доказать ему что не тупая домохозяйка.и еще я подзабыла математику и гиометрию хотя если начну решать что то не отстану

Comment: помогите решить .я знаю как написать начало и примерно как закончить но вот середину не могу понять как писать

Comment: Ну так учитесь, это сайт где помогают с конкретной проблемой, а не решают задачу за вас.

Comment: Мне кажется, чтобы доказать мужу, что вы не домохозяйка, надо суметь заставить себя открыть хорошую книгу по программированию, прочитать её и понять. И запрограммировать. Если ваша цель — выиграть спор у мужа, а не научиться программировать, для этого найдутся другие, менее затратные средства. Например, хороший борщ.

Comment: спасибо.за совет .мой борщ моему мужу очень нравится,но хотелось бы чтобы конечно ,кто-нибудь объяснил как писать эту задачу . вот мой вариант неправильного решенияfor (var N = 128;i = 0;i++) {
i *= N;
}
document.write(i);

Comment: @inessa: Раз вы уже пытались решить задачу, поместите ваш вариант (пускай неправильный) в вопрос, с этим он, вероятно, получит больше симпатии у сообщества. Но всё же я бы порекомендовал вам начинать с книги. Программист должен прежде всего уметь _учиться_.

Comment: спасибо большое ,прислушаюсь к вашему совету

Comment: Я голосую за переоткрытие этого вопроса, потому что http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2937/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, «потому что» что? по ссылке — вопрос «как "домашка" соотносится с "гольфом"?». и ничего больше. я голосую против переоткрытия.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку в метках только *Linux*, то вот:

```
#!/bin/bash

N=128
SUM=0

for ((i=1; i<=N; i++))
do
    SUM=$((SUM + i*i))
done

echo "Sum=$SUM"
```

Comment: А вот и не угадали! :-)

Comment: @Vartlok А да. Уже понял. Там квадраты везде. Ща поправлю.

Comment: Я вообще про язык) судя по комментарию автора ему нужен JS, а не баш.

Comment: @Vartlok Но как было написано! Явная конкатенация!

Comment: @Vartlok Комментарий появился потом ;-)

Comment: А где же мини-браузер? Предлагаю последнюю строку:
`echo "Sum=$SUM" | lynx --stdin`